# Camel route with independent message queue reader

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic, jbossfuse

I have application with web service interface which developed using camel on JBoss FUSE and I am saving the receiving messages in to Database without any issue. But now I need to enhance it to do some time consuming processes such as web service invocations.

My Idea is to add that receiving message in to MessageQueue and then send the web service call response. Then to do the time consuming process by reading the message queue. But my problem is whether it's possible to have background route running in camel to do such implementation.

I try to implement it using multicast but in there it's waiting until all the routes completed.

Below diagram shows the thing that I try to archive.

[image]

My problem is is it possible to send the response from route 1 before finishing the route two? If its possible how can I archive it using camel ?

I'm quite new to Camel development and I would like to know whether it's possible to accomplished above scenario. Please be kind enough to provide feedback about this  ?

Comment: It would be helpful if the question was re-worded for clarity or a diagram of the process flow you had in mind was included. It sounds like you are trying to do enrichment by calling a second web service and combing the original and the second web service response together before saving to the database. Please clarify-- is the save to the database before or after the second web service call? Does the db call need data from both the original and the second call?  A diagram would be super helpful.

Comment: My Idea is to save the request message on initial web service request in to database and add that message in to ActiveMQ, then send the response of web service. Then in background running route to read the ActiveMQ queue and do the time consuming process such as web service and update the database.  I have added the Diagram in to question as well. Thanks for your response

Comment: Look at the Wire Tap EIP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to do by using [Wire-Tap](http://camel.apache.org/wire-tap.html). As show on below

```
    <route id="initialRequest">
        <from uri="bean:webService" />
        <to uri="database:saveData" />
        <wireTap uri="activemq:queue:queueName" />    
        ...continue your respond send process
    </route>

    <route id="BackgroundLongProcess">
        <from uri="activemq:queue:queueName" />
        ... Do the required time consuming process 
    </route>
```

Then the BackgroundLongProcess will execute but initialRequest route will not wait until BackgroundLongProcess process finish. You can refer to the camelone documentation for more details.

Answer (score 2):

It is absolutely possible. This is an example:

```
<route id="HandleRequest">
    <from uri="http:incomingWebRequest" />
    <to uri="database:saveData" />
    <to uri="activemq:queue:queueName" />
    <to uri="bean:processWebRequest" />
    <to uri="http:sendResponse" />
</route>

<route id="BackgroundLongProcess">
    <from uri="activemq:queue:queueName" />
    <to uri="bean:timeConsumingProcess" />
    <to uri="database:updateProcessedData" />
</route>
```

In **HandleRequest** route, the body will be sent to an ActiveMQ queue. This is generally a fast operation.
**BackgroundLongProcess** route will be triggered asyncronously by ActiveMQ queue, and your processing can take longer.

In my example I sent the body to ActiveMQ and directly processed it, you can send a database primary key and reload the data from DB before processing it.

You can then develop your application in 2 different bundles, one that handles the HTTP part and one that does the background processing. This will improve modularity and you can update/start/stop each service independently. Messages stored in the queue **will be persisted** and processed when the processing bundle starts again.

http://camel.apache.org/activemq.html

Comment: Thanks for your solution and explanation. It would really help to understand more about camel. But I needed t archive it in single bundle.

Comment: @casper this solution works in single bundle and also in multi bundle. Communication between routes happens using ActiveMQ. I suggest reading "Camel in Action" and "OSGi in Action" books.